# Why doesn't Lodash's map method work in implicit chains?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given an object that looks like this:

```
let obj = { mytest: [{ mytest2: 123 }] }
```

I would have thought I could use the implicit chain like this:

```
_(obj).get('mytest').map('mytest2').value();
```

But I get an error:

```
VM922:1 Uncaught TypeError: mytest2 is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:22
(anonymous) @ VM922:1
```

It seems to expect the `map` parameter to be a function. If I use the explicit `chain` method then it does seem to work.

```
_.chain(obj).get('mytest').map('mytest2').value();
[123]
```

What's going on here? I'm using lodash 4.17.15.

Comment: I may have found a relevant bug issue in github, it appears that the implicit chain sequence doesn't support "lazy evaluation" (so i think implicit sequences require function parameters, rather than a string).

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3601

Answer (score 2):

The `_(obj)` is not an "implicit chain", it's a use-once object that wraps a value to make lodash functions available with method syntax. `_(obj).get('mytest')` is the same as `_.get(obj, 'mytest')`, and returns the raw `[{ mytest2: 123 }]` array. The `.map` method you're calling is not `_.map`, it's [the array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which requires a function argument. You also wouldn't need to call `.value()` on the return value.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you. I've confirmed that `_(obj).get('mytest')` does in fact return an array (and so map expects a function). What I am still a bit confused about though is why do other sequences work? I am unable to edit my question any more, but the following sequence does work: `_(arrOf2Objs).flatMap('mytest').map('mytest2').uniq().value();`. If its a "use-once" object, then why would the object still be a lodash object by the time we reach "uniq()"? Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. [Lodash documents `map` to be chainable](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash) (and only primitive-returning getters to implicitly end the chain), it must have been the [Underscore OOP](http://underscorejs.org/#oop) behaviour that I was remembering. I can't explain why `lodash(arr).map(…)` returns a plain array instead of a chainable object.